# cannot select active spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Why does Spreadsheet.getActiveSpreadsheet() not properly select the active spreadsheet?
I am following google's scripts codelab and came across a tutorial that is not replicable. I am trying to select my active sheet, then duplicate it.

```
function duplicateAndOrganizeActiveSheet() {
  var mySS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var duplicateSheet = mySS.duplicateActiveSheet();
}
```

When executing, this function returns "Exception: Please select an active sheet first."
Thus I am not able to duplicate my active sheet.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs when you run the script from the IDE and it does not have a "connection" to the spreadsheet.  For example, if you opened the script editor via a direct link and not the main menu.

Try re-opening the attached script via Main Menu -> Extensions -> Apps Script, then run the script again.

Comment: Thank you. It was weird because I was able to run other functions and select the active sheet, but not with the one above. But after reopening, it somehow works again.